# How to reload controller with all template inside in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to reload a page, for example with address '/tasks' when some action occours on page '/page' using angular-ui-router. How to do it?

```
$state.reload()
```

does not reload a HTML and controller. I also does not want to refresh page. Just rerender everything in controller template (with all subcomponents).

Regards

Comment: are u looking for complete page reload? you can do it using $route provider "$route.reload();"

Answer (score 0):

Try using $route provider. `$route.reload();`